# Restrict dynamic feature module to certain BuiltTypes

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle, dynamic-feature-module

I have an app with two flavors and 6 buildTypes. I'm developing a dynamic feature module, but I don't want it included in the release bundle. Is there a way to do this using buildTypes? I've tried adding the `dynamicFeatures = ["mymodule"]` within the desired buildTypes, but it still gets added to the release bundle. I know I can specify it as `on-demand` in the module's manifest to prevent it from being added to apks installed by users, but I'd prefer to keep it out of the release bundle all together. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I did:

I created another gradle file called `dynamic_features.gradle`. This is what it looks like:

```
if (hasProperty('is_release_build')) {
    android {
        buildTypes {
            debug {
                buildConfigField 'boolean', 'HAS_DYNAMIC_FEATURES', 'false'
            }
            qa {
                buildConfigField 'boolean', 'HAS_DYNAMIC_FEATURES', 'false'
            }
            release {
                buildConfigField 'boolean', 'HAS_DYNAMIC_FEATURES', 'false'
            }
            staging {
                buildConfigField 'boolean', 'HAS_DYNAMIC_FEATURES', 'false'
            }
            debugDaily {
                buildConfigField 'boolean', 'HAS_DYNAMIC_FEATURES', 'false'
            }
            local {
                buildConfigField 'boolean', 'HAS_DYNAMIC_FEATURES', 'false'
            }
        }
    }
} else {
    android {
        buildTypes {
            debug {
                buildConfigField 'boolean', 'HAS_DYNAMIC_FEATURES', 'true'
            }
            qa {
                buildConfigField 'boolean', 'HAS_DYNAMIC_FEATURES', 'true'
            }
            release {
                buildConfigField 'boolean', 'HAS_DYNAMIC_FEATURES', 'true'
            }
            staging {
                buildConfigField 'boolean', 'HAS_DYNAMIC_FEATURES', 'true'
            }
            debugDaily {
                buildConfigField 'boolean', 'HAS_DYNAMIC_FEATURES', 'true'
            }
            local {
                buildConfigField 'boolean', 'HAS_DYNAMIC_FEATURES', 'true'
            }
        }

        dynamicFeatures = [":<features>"]
    }
}
```

Then, I added `-Pis_release_build` to my build script: `./gradlew clean bundleAppRelease -Pis_release_build`.

Finally, I added `apply from: 'dynamic_features.gradle'` to my app level `build.gradle`. Bundles generated with the build script don't include the feature module. The `buildConfigField` is optional, but useful if you want to check whether or not that feature is available at runtime.